# Google App Engine Invalid PUBLIC ID: -//Oracle Corporation//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN

Tags: java, oracle, google-app-engine

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code

when i get to deploy the application on my localhost dev server, the app is deployed just fine:

```
[INFO] INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

however, upon trying to go to the home page `http://localhost:8080`, i get this weird error:

```
[INFO] SEVERE: Invalid PUBLIC ID: -//Oracle Corporation//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN
```

what is going on?

i'm using the `web.xml` they gave, which is here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code#configuring_webxml

Answer (score 1):

o...my... god... the tutorial is broken. i had to go hunt down the [github code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-guestbook-multiphase/blob/master/final/guestbook-war/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) to figure it out:

you have to use

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

in the xml.